# Undecorated Names not correct.... [undname.exe VS-2019]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

There are two overloads for CDialog. Clearly the mangled names are different..

?Create@CDialog@@$$FUAEHIPAVCWnd@@@Z
?Create@CDialog@@UAEHIPAVCWnd@@@Z

However, undname.exe does not properly determine that one overload is an LPCSTR...

> undname.exe ?Create@CDialog@@UAEHIPAVCWnd@@@Z
> Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "?Create@CDialog@@UAEHIPAVCWnd@@@Z"
is :- "public: virtual int __thiscall CDialog::Create(unsigned int,class CWnd *)"

> undname.exe ?Create@CDialog@@$$FUAEHIPAVCWnd@@@Z
> Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "?Create@CDialog@@$$FUAEHIPAVCWnd@@@Z"
is :- "public: virtual int __thiscall CDialog::Create(unsigned int,class CWnd *)"

Comment: Note the names are VERY similar, but the "$$F" portiuon of the first overload is not apparently being recognized by undname.exe.   This behaviour is replicated (in fact what started this) when calling UnDecorateSymbolName directly....

Comment: Looks like a bug (oversight).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - Do you have any link to support that?